# Why does SSH client and FileZilla turn unresponsive after a minute

Tags: linux, centos, vps

Mine is Centos based VPS with Cpanel.

When I connect to this server from my PC using SSH or open FileZilla to transfer files they both turn unresponsive after I leave them idle for a minute or so.

Previously it was all fine and would work for hours too.

I guess my provider may have done some setting.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess  you have root SSH acess, since this is a VPS. If not contact the vps provider.

You can login in root and  make following changes.

. Open   `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

. Add or modify the current entries to below one

> ClientAliveInterval 600 
>       ClientAliveCountMax 3

. Restart the sshd process.

> service sshd restart

This will keep you logged in for 30 minutes at a time without activity. (600 seconds x 3)

PS: Please make sure you backup the configuration file before editing it.

Comment: No it does not work. Moreover I've mentioned specifically that it is similar issue with both ftp and ssh.